# Bokeh Convert Number to Money String in Hover

Tags: python, bokeh

I am using Python 3.6 and Bokeh 0.13.

In hovering over a bar chart, I would like to display a float as a money string where there is no decimal amount and there is a money sign in front of the number. Below is what I have so far for the tooltip.

```
tooltip_net_rev = [("Net Revenue", "$@y{int}")]
```

Which renders a string like what's shown below. This gets me most of the way there except for the commas.

```
Net Revenue: $128451
```

Here is what I would like it to look like with commas.

```
Net Revenue: $128,451
```

Any help with the tooltip formatting would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK `{int}` is not a meaningful format specifier for Bokeh tooltips, and if it is displaying anything at all, that's only because the unknown specifier is being ignored. There is fairly detailed documentation on formatting hover tooltips in the [Formatting Tooltip Fields](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#formatting-tooltip-fields) section of the User's Guide. Offhand, it looks like you want something like:

```
tooltip_net_rev = [("Net Revenue", "%@y{0,0.00}")]
```

Comment: Thank you, "$@y{0,0}" did it for me.